# Analyzing single cells from Excel to Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

So I have a folder of csv files that I want to iterate through to create a dataframe from. I've been able to iterate through and create the dataframe with the name of each csv as the index but the one thing I haven't been able to do is that all the csv's have a cell, A2, that says "latitude:xxxxxx" and I want to create a column, called latitude, that contains all these different lat values for each csv. How would I go about doing this?

What I have for iterating through the csv files:

```
for fn in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\joshs_000\\Desktop\\WindProject\\BayAreaData'):
    if fn.endswith(".csv"):
        df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\joshs_000\\Desktop\\WindProject\\BayAreaData\\' + fn, skiprows = 3)
        df2 = df2['power (MW)']
        df1[fn[:5]] = df2
```

Each of the dataframe contains in cells A1 and A2, the latitude and longitude in single cells, below that is the table that I copy over, hence the skiprows. I'm looking to be able to get the lat and lon into the dataframe as well but I'm unsure on how to analyze single cells with Pandas.

Comment: You could edit the question to include your attempt so far, along with a small input sample and your expected output. That would help us to determine exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve this with a single pandas command. The simplest solution would simply be to create a separate dataframe for the longitude/latitude data. Something along the lines of:

```
import csv

row_list = []
for fn in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\joshs_000\\Desktop\\WindProject\\BayAreaData'):
    if fn.endswith(".csv"):
        with open(fn, 'r', newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            row_list.append([fn] + next(reader))
df_location = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=['filename', 'longitude', 'latitude'])
df_location.set_index(['filename'])
```

This dataframe is now indexed to the filename, so adding data to the original dataframe should be easy.